# In MySql, how do I group based on one column and do sums on others?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to print a report based on my sales tables but having a hard time writing my query.

```
 +----------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+
 |                      SALES                        |
 +----------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+
 | agent_id |  type  |  result   | value |    date    |
 +----------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+
 |        1 | sales  | yes       | 12.34 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        1 | sales  | yes       |  5.45 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        1 | return | other     |  7.00 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        1 | return | saved     | 19.99 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        1 | return | not_saved |  1.19 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        2 | return | saved     |  1.34 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        2 | return | not_saved | 29.04 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        2 | sales  | yes       | 11.11 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        3 | sales  | no        | 10.00 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        3 | sales  | no        | 89.34 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        3 | sales  | yes       |  1.41 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        3 | sales  | other     |  2.41 | 2018-05-01 |
 |        3 | sales  | other     |  2.41 | 2018-04-28 |
 +----------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+
```

I'm having a hard time with columns 3, 4 and 5 in my query below.

COLUMN1 = agent_id

COLUMN2 = number of calls.
          This is the number of records each agent has

COLUMN3 = Number of Saves.
          This would be a count on the records where `type` is 'sales' and `result` is 'yes'

COLUMN4 = The value for saves.
          This is the sum(value) where `type` = "sales" and `result`="yes"

COLUMN5 = conversion rate.
          this would be (column3/column2)x100

This query is as far as I could get. I can't figure out the rest. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

```
SELECT agent_id,count(*) AS 'Number of Calls',COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5 
FROM sales 
WHERE comm_ts > '2018-04-29' 
GROUP BY agent_id;
```

This would be my result set

```
 +----------+--------+----------+-------+------------+---------+------------+
 | agent_id |  Number of Calls  |     COLUMN3        | COLUMN4 |   COLUMN5  |
 +----------+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------------+
 |        1 |       5          |        2           | 17.79   |     40%    |
 |        2 |       3          |        1           |  11.11  |     33%    |
 |        3 |       4          |        1           |  1.41   |     25%    |
 +----------+--------+----------+--------------------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: What do you actually want the result to be? Please edit your question and include a detailed description of the expected results and an example matching the given sample data.

Comment: *COLUMN4 = The value for saves. This is the sum(value) where type = "sales" and result="yes"* i imagined on using subquery (another select on the column).. but it seems will be expensive.. but can't help it, you had `if` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT agent_id, count(*) AS num_calls,
       sum(case when type = 'sales' and result = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as column3,
       sum(case when type = 'sales' and result = 'yes' then value else 0 end) as column4,
       avg(case when type = 'sales' and result = 'yes' then 1.0 else 0 end) as column5
FROM sales 
WHERE comm_ts > '2018-04-29' 
GROUP BY agent_id;
```